# How does one conditionally format a cell based on another cell's value in excel?

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, formatting

I have been searching high and low for a formula that will help me highlight a cell if the cell next to it contains a date.

For example:
If cell M2 contains a date, then I want cell L2 to be highlighted a certain way.

I don't want the entire row to be highlighted, just cell L2.

So far, from my readings on the Internet, I have gathered that the excel conditioning formatting option to use is "Format values where this formula is true", and that the formula will look something like this:

=CELL("format",**[cell on which the formula hinges on]**)=**[what the cell should contain for the formatting to take place]**

I have tried this but it did not work for me:
=CELL("format",$M2)="D1"

(D1 is the date format found in the cell in Column M.)

Please could someone point me towards the right way? Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
For more context, here is an image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NQwg.png)

In case it matters, the column L cells have been filled with this formula =IF(K2<>"","Ready to convert","") and they work well. After the L cell is filled up, M will be filled up afterwards by an RPA. I want L to be greyed out like M once M contains a date.

[2nd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrtCq.png)

FINAL EDIT:
I finally found a way to highlight a cell if the cell next to it contains a date. It turned out to be a lot simpler than expected - it's the way Excel works. The rule must contain the formula for the determining cell that will influence the formatting (in my case, column M), and then the "Applies to" column is for all the cells that will be affected (in my case, columns L and M)!!! It has nothing to do with having a formula in the column L cells.

Behold, [the formula,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jo6J.png) [and the desired result!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tMKT.png)

Thank you to those who have helped me along!

Comment: Are you sure this formula =CELL("format",$M2) returns D1?

Comment: **[CELL()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf)** function returns `D1` if the cells are formatted as `d-mmm-yy or dd-mmm-yy` Can you post a copiable data by editing the post so we can reproduce the example

Comment: Hi @MayukhBhattacharya, I have posted a link to an image showing you the data. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi @user11222393, yes I believe so. My dates are in dd-mm-yyyy format. EDIT: Oh wait, nevermind, I'm seeing that D1 is supposed to be dd-mmm-yy or d-mmm-yy according to the other commentor.

Comment: Just enter formula =CELL("format",$M2) anywhere ant see what result is returned

Comment: Hi @user11222393, thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't work though.

Comment: Hi @llamagirl please check and confirm the screenshot **[Formatting](https://imgur.com/gallery/5SH7HpN)**

Comment: Hi @MayukhBhattacharya, thanks for the screenshot. This is what I'm seeing: (please see the 2nd screenshot in the post) It only works for 1 row and not all the rows for "Step 1".

Comment: @llamagirl ok I will update, will you be able to confirm now?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya yes I confirm that the formatting is correct. Thanks!